# Google Visualization large array tables

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, etl, bigdata

Problem using Google Visualization with large arrays. I am simply trying to create a dataview from a table with 80,000 rows and the request to google freezes up. Specifically:

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([80,000rows,3 columns])

  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  dataView.setRows(5, 10);//display 5 rows
```

Google visualization creates the 5 row display I need if there are 30,000rows in the "data" array but it gets stuck with 80,000

Does anyone know how to get Google Visualization on big data tables?
If not what is an open source tool for very basic ETL and Visualization?

Comment: Have you tried creating a dataTable and using data.addColumn(); and data.addRow(); to input your data? This will likely be much faster. Also, is it possible to put the data in to a Google Spreadsheet and use [queries](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/queries) to import in to your chart? That should be even faster still. 80,000 lines of data is quite a lot, after all, and will take time to handle (even a thousand lines takes time to process, 80,000 would be many times that).

Comment: I love the addRow() idea, i wonder if the dataTable will run thatway.. the Google spreadsheet was my first try, I was crossing my fingers that it just worked :), but it won't take all those rows and its so slow..